# TeamCity messages folder growth

Tags: teamcity

My teamcity server diskspace is running very low.
The main growing folder is the "Messages" folder and i'm wonder how i can define the clean-up policy to delete old logs from the messages folder.

Currently my clean-up rule looks like that:

```
History more than 15 days older than the last build and older than the 50th successful build
Artifacts more than 2 days older than the last build and older than the 10th successful build; artifact patterns: +:\\**\\*
Other items are kept forever
Do not prevent dependency artifacts cleanup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be far from the most efficient solution, but this is my powershell script that goes through the Message folder and deletes all the index (*.i1) files that do not have corresponding message (*.msg5). Takes a bit of time, but if you schedule it on sunday job in TC, you don`t have to worry about oweflowing Message folder ever again. Using TeamCity against it.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$messageFolder = "G:\TeamCity\Data\system\messages"
)

function HasNoMessage {
    param([System.IO.FileInfo]$indexFile)

    foreach ($message in $messages)
    {
        if ($indexFile.Name.Contains($message.name))
        {
            return $false
        }
    }
    return $true
}

$folders = Get-ChildItem $messageFolder -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
$count = 0
$totalSize = 0
$preserved = 0

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    $table = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -include *.i1 -recurse 
    $messages = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -include *.msg5 -recurse
    foreach ($index in $table)
    {
        if (HasNoMessage($index))
        {
            $count++
            $totalSize += $index.Length
            remove-item $index.FullName 
        }
        else {$preserved++}
    }
} 
Write-Output("Finished : total files removed : ", $count)
Write-Output("Total size cleaned in MegaBytes : ", ($totalSize / 1MB))
Write-Output("Preserved files : ",  $preserved)
```

UPDATE : The new TeamCity version 9.x already has this taken care of so I strongly recomend to migrate

Answer (score 3):

If you are running TeamCity 8 or older then there is a known issue that the messages folder is not cleaned correctly, check out the following links for workarounds (basically manually deleting the files that are not used anymore):

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5518176#5518176

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-36830#comment=27-754144